# What does this "There is an error in XML document" error in DXA mean?

Tags: dxa

On a DXA .NET 1.6 website I get this internal server error on a page I just created:

[image: error message]

The site.log raises this error which is not very descriptive at first sight:

`2016-11-15 11:22:27,335 [32] ERROR - There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> was not expected.
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read32_Page()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.PageSerializer.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at DD4T.Serialization.XmlSerializerService.Deserialize[T](String input)
   at DD4T.Factories.FactoryBase.AutoDetectSerializerService.Deserialize[T](String input)
   at DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.GetIPageObject(String pageStringContent)
   at DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage& page)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPage(String urlPath, Localization localization)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes)
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl)`

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs when DXA cannot read the page JSON. The trace gives a hint: `DD4T.Serialization.XmlSerializerService.Deserialize`, DD4T is trying to deserialize the page XML while XML is not expected, DXA publishes pages as JSON.

The problem is that page template or component template are not using a DXA template but a default template from SDL, or another template which does not produce the expected JSON output.

For example: The "Default Page Template" in this screenshot is installed with SDL Web and renders HTML. We should use the Content Page (a standard DXA template) instead.
[image: page settings]

Btw, this error is not specific to DXA version 1.6 for .NET, since the root of the problem is in the page template used for the page a similar error would occur in other DXA versions and on JAVA.